# Dynamic Handling of GotFocus Event in vba

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, focus

I have some vba code that automatically creates a few ActiveX comboboxes. In order to handle their events I fill a global Collection with CComboEvent objects (custom class that I wrote, see below), one for every combobox. The CComboEvent objects should handle the events. While cbx_Change() in the code below works as expected, cbx_GotFocus() does not fire.

I feel like I'm overseeing something, can anyone please help?

Thank you

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents Cbx As MSForms.ComboBox

Private Sub Cbx_Change()
    ' TODO: Filter data that is shown in ListFillRange
    ' For now just show that the event fires:
    MsgBox Cbx.Value  ' This works as expected on every key stroke
End Sub

Private Sub Cbx_GotFocus()
    MsgBox "FOCUS!"  ' Never shown
    ' Open the dropdown list
    Cbx.ListFillRange = "A1:A11"
    Cbx.DropDown
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you get the same event to fire outside of your class?  Also [this post](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=49836&p=253945#post253945) indicates you cannot focus on a `ComboBox` on a `Worksheet`.  Might want to try `Activate` instead.  Or provide more detail about where these are being created.

Comment: If I create a new workbook, insert a ComboBox on it and double click the ComboBox, it creates the change event handler automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Byron. Yes, GotFocus works outside my class like this: create workbook, insert ComboBox, double click it. This creates the change event handler automatically: `Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()`. Similar to that I can create the GotFocus event handler. While this works when written simply as a worksheet function, it doesn't inside my class.
`Activate` also didn't work, which is fine. From the link you posted I understand `Activate` would move focus to the ComboBox by vba code. I don't want that. I want to detect when the user enters the ComboBox himself and respond to that.

Comment: Ah, now I see it.  Unfortunately, it looks like we are not the first on the case to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761973/accessing-oleobject-events-in-excel-vba-using-custom-class and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390289/how-to-assign-an-event-to-multiple-objects-with-excel-vba.  I was able to get a very similar effect though using `MouseDown` instead of `GotFocus` which does not exist.

Comment: Long time has passed, but still: thanks @byron-wall for pointing me in the right direction. Starting with the links you sent me, I was able to adjust the requirements a bit and build a workable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question properly: the reason `Cbx_GotFocus()` never fires is that it really isn't available to `MSForms.ComboBox` in this context. The available events can be checked like this:

1. Open the left drop down list above the vba editor window and choose the class element you want to respond to events for[image: Choose element]
2. Open the right drop down list above the vba editor window to see which events are avalable [image: Choose event]

This is a trick that you can use at different occasions to check for built in events/functions in vba. A shame that I didn't think of it right away. I finally ended up using a combination of `Cbx_KeyUp()` and `Cbx_DropButtonClick()` to respond to user interactions in that particular project.