# Trigger ComboBox 2 DropDownClick in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two comobboxes CB3 and CB2. What I want to do is when CB2 is blank and CB3 is clicked to have an error msgbox that says please select an item in CB2 and at the same time trigger CB2's DROPBUTTONCLICK EVENT. Does anyone know how to code this? Thanks!

```
If ComboBox2.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Please select a CB2")
 End if
```

Comment: Are these comboboxes in a UserForm or are they just on the worksheet?

Comment: [Check out this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761973/accessing-oleobject-events-in-excel-vba-using-custom-class)  to see if you can create a solution out of it. [This might also be of help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994235/handling-events-for-oleobject-commandbuttons-created-at-runtime)