# Creating events for checkbox at runtime Excel VBA

Tags: excel, class, vba

I am modifying the answer in this thread to make it work for my code but it is not working for me.

[How to assign an event to multiple objects with excel vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390289/how-to-assign-an-event-to-multiple-objects-with-excel-vba)

A couple of differences, I am using a checkbox instead of a combobox but more importantly, I am creating my checkbox at runtime.

Here is my class:

```
Public WithEvents checkBox1 As MSForms.checkBox


Private Sub checkBox1_Click()
MsgBox "click"
End Sub'
```

module code:

```
Dim tbCollection As New Collection

Sub macro1()

Dim cbox As OLEObject
Dim myCheckBox As New JohnClass

Set cbox = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", Left:=Range("A1"))
Set myCheckBox.checkBox1 = cbox.Object
tbCollection.Add cbox
end sub
```

I can see that I have a reference to the newly created check box because I can change the caption but when I click on it, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the instance of the custom class to the collection.  Change

```
tbCollection.Add cbox
```

to

```
tbCollection.Add myCheckBox
```

**Update:**

There seems to be some problem with adding OLEObjects at runtime and running any other code. I don't know what the problem is, but this seems to work.

```
Public tbCollection As Collection

Sub macro1()

    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", Left:=1, Top:=1

    Application.OnTime Now, "AddToClass"

End Sub

Sub AddToClass()

    Dim myCheckBox As JohnClass

    Set tbCollection = New Collection
    Set myCheckBox = New JohnClass

    Set myCheckBox.CheckBox1 = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Count).Object
    tbCollection.Add myCheckBox

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dick, I made the change as per your reply but I still do not see the event being fired when I click on the checkbox.